# Counting based on two columns in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif

I have the following table in Excel:

> ```
> Name      Col_A        Col_B
> Michael   Some_value  
> Alex      Some_value  Some_value
> Jennifer
> ```

I want to count in a single cell (without adding any columns to assist me) how many names I have that have at a value at least in one of the columns A or B. So in this case the result will be 2.
I tried to do it with COUNTIFS and COUNT (IF) but it seems to cover only one column at a time.

Comment: Try using `MMULT()` ==> `=SUM(N(MMULT(--(D4:E6<>""),{1;1})>0))` where `D4:E6` is Col A & Col B respectively

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want a helper column? You could hide it.

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya it seems to work thanks!
Can you explain the syntax? what does "--" stand for?

Comment: @Alex just posted you can refer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `MMULT()`

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `F4`

```
=SUM(N(MMULT(--(D4:E6<>""),{1;1})>0))
```

---

So, we can use either `--` or `N()` which means

> The double unary (also called a double negative) is an operation used
> to coerce TRUE FALSE values to ones and zeros in more advanced
> formulas, especially formulas that work with arrays.

---

> While `N()` function converts non-number values to a number, dates to
> serial numberss, TRUE to 1 and anything else to 0

---

**Note:** Source for `--` taken from [exceljet.net](https://exceljet.net/glossary/double-unary#)